# Trying to compute this simple integral with hyperboxes

Tags: integration

Suppose that i have a partition $\mathcal{L}$ of the unit hypercube $\mathbb{I} = [0,1]^d$, **made only of hyperboxes** $\ell = [a(\ell),b(\ell)]$ where $a(\ell) \in \mathbb{I}, b(\ell)\in \mathbb{I}$ and $a(\ell)_i \le b(\ell)_i$ for all dimension $i$.

Suppose that $\ell$ and $k$ are two sets in this partition. **I want to disjunct cases to compute the integral :**

$$B(\ell,k) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{I}} \mathbb{1}_{u \in \ell} \; \lambda([0,u]\cap k) \;du$$

Where $\lambda(s)$ denotes the lebesgue measure of a set $s$ :

$$\lambda(s) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^d  \left(b(s)_i - a(s)_i\right) = \int\limits_{s}\;du$$

I already have the two simplest cases :

1° If for all $i$, $a(\ell)_i \ge b(k)_i$, $B(l,k) = \lambda(l)\lambda(k)$ since $\lambda([0,u]\cap k) = \lambda(k)$ for all $u \in \ell$.

2° If there exist $i$ such that $b(\ell)_i \le a(k)_i$, $B(l,k) = 0$.

What now about all other cases, cases where some marginal projection of the hyperboxes $l$ and $k$ **do** overlapp ? The case disjunction (and hence the implementation later) could be simplified if the integral could be splitted as :

$$B(l,k) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \;\int\limits_{[0,1]} \mathbb{1}_{u_i \in \ell_i} \; \lambda([0,u_i]\cap k_i) \;du_i$$

Which i'm not shure i can do.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by translating this into simpler notation. $l, k \subseteq [0,1]^d$, where

$$l = \prod_i [a_i, b_i], \qquad k = \prod_i [c_i, d_i]$$

For any $u \in [0,1]^d$, define $L(u) = \{x \in [0,1]^d\mid \forall i, x_i \le u_i\}$ and $\mu_k(u)$ to be the hypervolume of $L(u) \cap k$.

Now $$L(u) \cap k = \prod_i [c_i, \min\{u_i, d_i\}]$$ (where $[p,q] := \emptyset$ when $q < p$). Also let $$\phi(p, q; r) = \begin{cases} 0, & r \le p\\r-p, & p< r < q\\q-p,& r \le q\end{cases}$$ for all real numbers $p,q,r$. Then
 $$\mu_k(u) = \prod_i \phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)$$

You want to compute $$\begin{align}B(l,k) &= \int_l \mu_k(u)\, du \\&= \int_{a_1}^{b_1}\int_{a_2}^{b_2}\dots\int_{a_d}^{b_d} \prod_i \phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_1du_2\dots du_d\\&= \int_{a_1}^{b_1}\phi(c_1, d_1; u_1)\,du_1\int_{a_2}^{b_2}\phi(c_2, d_2; u_2)\,du_2\dots\int_{a_d}^{b_d}\phi(c_d, d_d; u_d)\,du_d \\&= \prod_i\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i\end{align}$$

For each index $i$, we can break this into cases:

- $a_i < b_i \le c_i < d_i$: $$\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i = \int_{a_i}^{b_i}0\,du_i= 0$$
- $a_i \le c_i < b_i \le d_i$: $$\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i = \int_{a_i}^{c_i}0\,du_i + \int_{c_i}^{b_i}u_i - c_i\,du_i = \frac{(b_i - c_i)^2}2$$
- $c_i < a_i < b_i \le d_i$: $$\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i = \int_{a_i}^{b_i}u_i - c_i\,du_i = \frac{(b_i - a_i)(a_i + b_i - 2c_i)}2$$
- $a_i \le c_i < d_i < b_i$: $$\begin{align}\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i &= \int_{a_i}^{c_i}0\,du_i + \int_{c_i}^{d_i}u_i - c_i\,du_i + \int_{d_i}^{b_i}d_i - c_i\,du_i\\&= 0 + \frac{(d_i - c_i)^2}2 + (b_i - d_i)(d_i - c_i)\\&=\frac{(d_i-c_i)(2b _i + c_i - d_i)}2\end{align}$$
- $c_i < a_i < d_i < b_i$: $$\begin{align}\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i &= \int_{a_i}^{d_i}u_i - c_i\,du_i + \int_{d_i}^{b_i}d_i - c_i\,du_i\\&=\frac{(d_i - a_i)(a_i - 2c_i+ d_i)}2 + (b_i - d_i)(d_i - c_i) \end{align}$$
- $c_i < d_i \le a_i < b_i$: $$\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\phi(c_i, d_i; u_i)\,du_i = \int_{a_i}^{b_i}d_i - c_i\,du_i = (b_i - a_i)(d_i - c_i)$$

If there is an index $j$ with $b_j \le c_j$, then we can say immediately that $B(l,k) = 0$. Otherwise, you'll have to calculate each index value separately, then take their product.

Comment: @lrnv - I apologize for rejecting your change, then making it myself. I was rushed when i first saw it and didn't give it a careful enough examination. But when I had more time, I found the sign error and fixed it. Last night when I did these, I was trying to do too much at once. I copied from the first erroneous formula into another one later, so it was also incorrect. I have now changed the both, and double checked the others.

Comment: To have a more concise view of what's happening, i redraw the conditioning by splitting the integral into 3 parts, and then using the $a\wedge b$ notation in the bounds. This makes the calculations less cumbersome since the disjunction is hidden in the notation. Thanks anyway for taking the time, you really helped me ;)